# Auto sizing cells/dynamic font in ios8

Tags: ios, ios8

I am updating several apps from iOS7 to iOS8 and am adjusting to the new AutoSizing Cell and Dynamic Font. I have nearly everything working (Auto Layout is on and I'm capturing the font change via the notification center to reload the table).  However, one case is still not working correctly.  When I change the font on the iPad Air to the largest setting (slider in settings all the way right), I get the following:

[image]

How can I prevent this? If I drop the font size down just one level, all is fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One thing I have noticed in Apple's Settings behavior...it seems they somehow limit the font size of the Footer, i.e. no noticeable difference between the max Font size setting and the next one down.  How is this possible?  I'm using TitleForFooter to set the footer info up as you see in the screen shot.

Comment: Also..how would one set the max size of a cell when it's being built programmatically? I can not simply create a IBOutlet constraint to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely auto sizing is not working.
You must set tableView.estimatedRowHeight and tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. I assume you did. Than it is up to constrains to provide correct sizes.

Can you post image with constrains?

Comment: This is a dynamic cell that is built programmatically.  I don't have any constraints set.  How would I do that for a cell like this?

Comment: I do havetableView.estimatedRowHeight and tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension set in ViewDidLoad.  Makes no difference if they are there or not.

Comment: without constrains it will not work. constrains are mandatory for that feature. You can add constrains programatically. Check it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Again, thank you for that input.  However, I do understand constraints...just not in this case.  What am I trying to constrain, the cell or the footer???

Comment: Oh..also, this is ONLY happening on the iPad.  I have similar code set up in another app for iPhone and it works just fine.  I'm wondering if it has to do with the limited width of the popover VC on the iPad.

Comment: can you share sample project where you show that error? just that one view?